# cannot get rid of error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses"

Tags: android, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

I wanted to run the command:

`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.1.1_r6`

and got the following output:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anu/bin/repo", line 91, in <module>
    import readline
ImportError: No module named readline`

So to fix the above, I tried to install readline using commands `pip install readline` and `easy_install readline`, but both the commands outputs the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have ubuntu 12.04 with python 2.7.3 and want to build android source code.

I searched a lot to fix it but no success... Can anybody point to me what I am missing?

Comment: Figure out what the ncurses-dev package is called on your distro and apt-get it.  You may be able to apt-get a python readline package rather than pip installing it.

Comment: I did everything but still get the same error anu@anu-Studio-1558:~$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anu/bin/repo", line 91, in <module>
    import readline
ImportError: No module named readline

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

And then rerun you command

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an 64 bit OS, you might have to install the i386 versions of the libraries. A lot (all?) of the Android host commands are 32-bit only.

Comment: Yes I am running this on 64 bit OS..I have installed i386 libraries but still not able to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed above issue by installing python 2.7 .Guess the repo works fine with previous version of python and not the current version 2.7.3.